# Default (fallback) Image with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, image, default

I'm curious if it's possible to use `.htaccess` to serve up a default image when a particular image is requested that doesn't exist (*note: only image-requests should raise this behavior*). I know I could do this with PHP by serving the images through a script, but I'm more curious if this can be done with .htaccess instead.

Suppose I request `/thumbnails/010.gif`, which doesn't exist. How could I get .htaccess to serve up `/thumbnails/default.gif` in its place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this will work for you.  Place this .htaccess in your thumbnails directory and any URIs below /thumbnails that do not exist will direct to /thumbnails/default.gif

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ default.gif [NC,L]
```

Comment: Seems like it does the trick. Can you restrict it to just calls for images, rather than any missing file? Perhaps (.png|.jpg|.gif|.jpeg)

Answer (score 2):

Since you just want to have it applied to */thumbnails/*:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^thumbnails/ thumbnails/default.gif
```

Answer (score 1):

If you send *only* images from this directory, you could utilize the [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) statement like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /thumbnails/default.gif
```

`/thumbnails` must be relative to your `DocumentRoot`.

I tested it with FF and it does as promised. However there could be issues with IE's "Don't display 404s that are smaller than some hundred KB" #%?$!